# Kubuntu 22.04 Widgets Repostioning problem

Tags: kubuntu, plasma, plasma-5, 22.04, widgets

I recently update Kubuntu 20.10 to 22.04. Every Thing is Fine except for the Plasma widgets. Kubuntu right now after update run on Kde plasma: 5.24.4 framework version: 5.92.0 Qt version: 5.15.3.
So the problem is when I drag widgets to the desktop and nicely configure them. after the reboot all widgets are scattered from the configured place, so anyone can find the solution to this then comment, please